# Angular: Updating controller scope variable through a factory variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I looked into examples on how to do this properly but it's definitely not updating on my end.  I put a breakpoint to make sure it's updating and going through the timer in the Factory and it's updating properly.  I shouldn't have to use $watch right?  If someone can help me figure out what's going on it would help with my headache right now lol thanks.

Factory

```
app.factory('FoundationSystemStatusFactory', ['$timeout', '$q', 'SystemStatusFactory', function ($timeout, $q, SystemStatusFactory) {
var service = {};

service.Count = 0;

service.Ping = 0;

service.PollingTest = function() {
    $timeout(function () {

        SystemStatusFactory.PingIP('www.google.com')
            .then(function (data) {
                service.Ping = data.data;
                service.Count++;
            }, function (data) {
                service.Ping = data.data;
            });

        service.PollingTest();
    }, 2000);
}

return service;

}]);
```

Controller

```
 FoundationSystemStatusFactory.PollingTest();

 $scope.ping = FoundationSystemStatusFactory.Ping;  //NOT UPDATING

 $scope.count = FoundationSystemStatusFactory.Count;  //NOT UPDATING
```

EDIT: tried as Service, still couldn't get it to work:

```
var self = this;

self.Count = 0;

self.Ping = 0;

self.PollingTest = function () {
    $timeout(function () {

        SystemStatusFactory.PingIP('www.google.com')
            .then(function (data) {
                self.Ping = data.data;
                self.Count++;
            }, function (data) {
                self.Ping = data.data;
            });

        self.PollingTest();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use service instead of factory?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly no let me try right now.  I keep looking up the difference between the two.. and other than the way that it's instantiated i still am confused at the difference between the two.

Comment: Simply factory returns data, service modifies data

Comment: It's not just about changing app.factory to app.service, you have change the logic,  read some docs, it's very easy

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly okay looking into it, thanks for the tip

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly tried as Service.  i edited OP.  still couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use watcher:

```
$scope.$watch('FoundationSystemStatusFactory.Ping', function(newValue) {
    $scope.ping = newValue;
});
```

Or you can use reference to factory:

```
$scope.status = FoundationSystemStatusFactory;

$interval(function() {
    console.log($scope.status.Ping);    // gets updated
});
```

Comment: i know $watch works, but i believe there's a proper way of accomplishing what i want without having to use $watch?  thank you for your answer

Comment: @user1189352 have you seen my second approach? Does it work for you?

Comment: hi sorry yes i did.  I'm sure that works as well and i'll use your approach if i can't get it to work.  I just dont want to "hack" it and rather try to learn / do it the proper way.. I'm positive I should be able to make it work without having to use $interval neither.

Comment: I included `$interval` only for demonstration purposes. The thing is, that when you write `$scope.status = FoundationSystemStatusFactory;`. `$sope.status` contains reference to factory. And when property of the factory changes, reference contains fresh non-copied data. Because basically reference is a link to a memory cell. When you write `$scope.ping = FoundationSystemStatusFactory.Ping;`. `$scope.ping` contains a value (not a reference). It is happening because `type of FoundationSystemStatusFactory.Ping === 'number'`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation!  helps put things in perspective

Answer (score 2):

A different approach - **events**.

```
app.factory('FoundationSystemStatusFactory', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q', 'SystemStatusFactory', function ($rootScope, $timeout, $q, SystemStatusFactory) {
var service = {
 Count: 0
};

service.PollingTest = function() {
    $timeout(function () {
        SystemStatusFactory.PingIP('www.google.com')
            .then(function (data) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('FoundationSystemStatus:ping', data.data);
                service.Count++;
            }).catch(function (data) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('FoundationSystemStatus:ping', data.data);
            });

        service.PollingTest();
    }, 2000);
}

return service;

}]);

//On controller...
$scope.$on('FoundationSystemStatus:ping', function(ping){
 $scope.ping = ping;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out how to do it after some more research.  Objects are referenced as numbers and strings are not.

Factory

```
app.factory('FoundationSystemStatusFactory', ['$timeout', '$q', 'SystemStatusFactory', function ($timeout, $q, SystemStatusFactory) {
var service = {};

service.Data = {
    Count: 0,
    Ping: 0
}

service.PollingTest = function() {
    $timeout(function () {

        SystemStatusFactory.PingIP('www.google.com')
            .then(function (data) {
                service.Data.Ping = data.data;
                service.Data.Count++;
            }, function (data) {
                service.Data.Ping = data.data;
            });

        service.PollingTest();
    }, 2000);
}

return service;
}]);
```

Controller

```
app.controller('SystemStatusController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'FoundationSystemStatusFactory',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, FoundationSystemStatusFactory) {

        FoundationSystemStatusFactory.PollingTest();

        $scope.data = FoundationSystemStatusFactory.Data;
}]);
```

View

```
{{data.Ping}}
{{data.Count}}
```

Comment: It is basically what I've suggested you. Also, sorry but phrase "Objects are referenced as numbers and strings are not." makes no sense.

Comment: @goliney ok i gave you the answer then